# Free Version of linux for iseries power5

Tags: linux, ibm-midrange

At work we have an old iseries server and we want to install Linux on it.

On the IBM website they says that Redhat Enterprise and SUSE Enterprise Server are supported, however, both of these cost money.

Is there a way to install a version of linux on an iSeries for free?

Comment: If Linux isn't a requirement then there is several BSD distributions you can consider, FreeBSD being the most popular one.

Answer (score 1):

What model machine do you have?
[OpenSuse](http://www.opensuse.org) is free and runs on a handful of pSereis/iSeries machines.

Comment: I can't find anywhere that is says iSeries is supported

Comment: Recent iSereis machines are simply pSeries machines running i/OS. The core hardware is the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Debian](http://debian.org/) might also work, I think the PowerPC version might be OK.

Comment: I think powerPc is for MAC

Comment: Are you sure? The Debian 6.0 Squeeze PPC version is for "Motorola/IBM PowerPC (powerpc)"

Comment: PowerPC is PowerPC, no matter if it's a Mac or a IBM.

Comment: I'm not sure I will give Debain a look

Answer (score 1):

You can check distrowatch:

> http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=ppc .

I did found isos for Fedora 12, Crux and Gentoo